# Изменить строку коннекта в DataSet

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть у меня датасет, приконнекченный к базе (Access, но это не суть важно), и вот решили базу паролем закрыть, но чтобы пароль в конфиге не светился. Я во всех формах подобавлял пароль к коннекту, а как-то это можно в одном месте сделать? Строку коннекта, которую он держит в настройках, поменять на лету не удалось, ридонли.

Причем у самого датасета строки подключения нет. Пришлось в каждом TableAdapter'е, на каждой форме дописывать, а это как-то некошерно...

Comment: Если вы обеспокоены безопасностью, то вы делаете неправильно. Вытащить пароль из кода не намного сложнее, чем вытащить его из конфига. Вы просто усложняете себе жизнь.

Comment: Да я себе полностью отдаю отчет, что против серьезного взлома это фиговый листочек. Это скорее, на мой взгляд, защита от "дурака" и "офисного несуна", но это требование заказчика. И как, на Ваш взгляд, сделать правильно? Буду благодарен за дельный совет.

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать отдельный класс, лучше статический, в основном namespace, например в файле Program.cs:

```
static class CommonData
{
  public static string Password = "password";
}
```

Его открытые свойства/методы будут доступны из любой формы:

```
string connString = "...password=" + CommonData.Password + "...";
```

Или же можно в начальной форме (главной) задать публичное поле и передать его в другие формы:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public string Password = "password";

    void Method()
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.PublicMethod(this);
    }
}

public class Form2 : Form
{
    public void PublicMethod(Form1 frm)
    {
        string connString = "...password=" + frm.Password + "...";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще и такой вариант - прикрепить файл настройки и там складывать строку подключения, а для сохранения инфо использовать пароль на файл, либо писать в другой кодировке(при вытаскивании перекодировать).